# Как поделить элементы списка на два других списка по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так, чтобы элементы списка со значениями <40 и >60, и >60 и <40, оказались в двух разных списках?

```
reviews_values = [
    [68,18], [81,19], [81,22], [15,75], [75,15], [17,72], 
    [24,75], [21,91], [76, 6], [12,74], [18,83], [20,62], 
    [21,82], [21,79], [84,15], [73,16], [88,25], [78,23], 
    [32, 81], [77, 35]]
reviews = pd.DataFrame(reviews_values, columns=['Цена', 'Качество'])

clients_1 = []
clients_2 = []
for client in list(reviews.values):
```

Я понимаю, что могу обратиться к элементу списка `list(reviews.values)[0][1]`, но я не соображу, как воспользоваться этим в цикле.

Comment: приведите пожалуйста в вопросе результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: вы, очевидно, поторопились с приятием правильного ответа. вам ниже предложили решение с помощью pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reviews_values = [
[68,18], [81,19], [81,22], [15,75], [75,15], [17,72],
[24,75], [21,91], [76, 6], [12,74], [18,83], [20,62],
[21,82], [21,79], [84,15], [73,16], [88,25], [78,23],
[32, 81], [77, 35]]

clients_1 = []
clients_2 = []

for client in reviews_values:
    if client[0] > 60 and client[1] < 40:
        clients_1.append(client)
    else:
        clients_2.append(client)

print('Data 1: ', clients_1)
print('Data 2: ', clients_2)
```

Вывод:

```
Data 1:  [[68, 18], [81, 19], [81, 22], [75, 15], [76, 6], [84, 15], [73, 16], [88, 25], [78, 23], [77, 35]]
Data 2:  [[15, 75], [17, 72], [24, 75], [21, 91], [12, 74], [18, 83], [20, 62], [21, 82], [21, 79], [32, 81]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [11]: qry1 = "Цена > 60 and Качество < 40"

In [12]: qry2 = "not (Цена > 60 and Качество < 40)"

In [13]: reviews.query(qry1)
Out[13]:
    Цена  Качество
0     68        18
1     81        19
2     81        22
4     75        15
8     76         6
14    84        15
15    73        16
16    88        25
17    78        23
19    77        35

In [14]: reviews.query(qry2)
Out[14]:
    Цена  Качество
3     15        75
5     17        72
6     24        75
7     21        91
9     12        74
10    18        83
11    20        62
12    21        82
13    21        79
18    32        81
```

Comment: видимо, ему нужно еще что-то типа `reviews.query(qry1).values.tolist()`

Comment: @strawdog, для меня это неочевидно, поэтому я [попросил автора уточнить какой результат он ожидает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1123768/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc/1123785?noredirect=1#comment1941847_1123768)